# Python: Divide row in one DataFrame by all rows in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I have two DataFrames as follows:

```
df1:
       A      B      C       D
index
    0  10000  20000  30000   40000

df2:
      time    type  A     B      C     D
index
    0 5/2020  unit  1000  4000   900   200
    1 6/2020  unit  7000  2000   600   4000
```

I want to divide `df1.iloc[0]` by all rows in df2 to get the following:

```
df:
      time    type  A     B    C       D
index
    0 5/2020  unit  10    5    33.33   200
    1 6/2020  unit  1.43  10   50      10
```

I tried to use `df1.iloc[0].div(df2.iloc[:])` but that gave me NaNs for all rows other than the 0 index.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
df2.update(df2.loc[:,df1.columns].rdiv(df1.iloc[0]))
df2
Out[861]: 
     time  type          A     B          C      D
0  5/2020  unit  10.000000   5.0  33.333333  200.0
1  6/2020  unit   1.428571  10.0  50.000000   10.0
```

Comment: Actually both `div` or `rdiv` throws ZeroDivisionError if one of the divisor is 0, how to avoid it without complex logic of checking if zero is present in series or not. Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html).

```
df = df2.apply(lambda x:df1.iloc[0].div(x[df1.columns]), axis=1)
```

print(df):

```
               A     B          C      D
index                                   
0      10.000000   5.0  33.333333  200.0
1       1.428571  10.0  50.000000   10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

another way to do it, using numpy divide

```
df2.update(np.divide(df.to_numpy()[:,:], df2.loc[:,df.columns]))
df2
```

```
    time    type    A           B       C           D
0   5/2020  unit    10.000000   5.0     33.333333   200.0
1   6/2020  unit    1.428571    10.0    50.000000   10.0
```